# Many-to-many navigation property is null when using inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using inheritance with C#/MVC. I have a parent class, `Parent`, with various properties, and a child, `Child`, that inherits from `Parent` and adds a property for a many-to-many relationship. I read elsewhere a while ago that handling this properly with inheritance requires an overridden method to return `Child`'s property, so I'm trying to do that (because C# won't recognize `Child`'s property and therefore can't directly query it).

The method always returns `null`, however, and the actual navigation property on the parent type is also `null`. What am I doing incorrectly with this method and/or mapping?

`Parent`:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    // other irrelevant properties

    public virtual ICollection<Property> GetChildProps()
    {
        // meant to be overridden by Child
        return null;
    }

    public virtual void SetChildProps(ICollection<Property> props)
    {
        // meant to be overridden by Child
    }
}
```

`Child`:

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    public ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }

    public override ICollection<Property> GetChildProps()
    {
        return Properties;
    }

    public override void SetChildProps(ICollection<Property> props)
    {
        Properties = props;
    }
}
```

EF Mapping. Most of the mapping is done in the parent class map (using EF TPH), but this relationship is mapped here. Values **are** being properly stored in the DB.

```
public ChildTaskMap()
    {
        HasMany(s => s.Properties)
            .WithMany(o => o.Children)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("Child_Properties");
                m.MapLeftKey("ChildId");
                m.MapRightKey("PropertyId");
            });
    }
```

This is one of the times I call `GetChildProps()` (always returns null):

```
Parent p = _parentService.GetParentById(id);
var cProps = p.GetChildProps();
```

Code for `GetParentById()`:

```
public Project GetById(int id)
{
    return _parentRepository.GetById(id);
}

// then

public T GetById(object id)
{
    return this.Entities.Find(id);
}

// Entities is

private IDbSet<T> Entities
{
    get
    {
        if (_entities == null)
            _entities = _context.Set<T>();
            // _entities is an IDbSet<T>
        return _entities;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your GetParentById code?

Comment: @JamieD77 Added it to the OP. It calls a repository.

Comment: i'm still trying to see where you're loading the `Properties` property.  Unless you have lazy loading set to true, you'll need to `Include` Properties in your dbcontext query

Comment: Properties should also be virtual..   `public virtual ICollection<Property> Properties`

Comment: @JamieD77 I see now what you were asking. The full stack is now there; the ultimate call is `IDbSet<T>.Find(id)`. I also made the `ICollection` virtual, that was an oversight, thank you!

Comment: Here is a good article regarding loading related entities that might help you  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: @JamieD77 I should have clarified--I'm working within a framework (NopCommerce), those last two functions are buried deep within the core files. I can add my own that forces eager loading with `Include`, but I'd rather not if it can be helped.

Comment: please check again what the actual underlying element type of `p` returned by `_parentService.GetParentById(id)`. Because `Parent` is not abstract, so there is a high chance that all the elements in the result are purely `Parent` (not `Child`). So how could it call to the `Child`'s method? Virtual can just help doing so if the current instance is just actually a `Child` (but maybe wrapped / boxed by `Parent`).